# What is the difference between using "Binding with StaticResource" and using "StaticResource directly" in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have created a `mycustomItemsPanel` in `App.Resources`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="mycustomItemsPanel">
        .... Some code here
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

and providing this to a UIControl this way

```
<.... ItemsPanel="{StaticResource mycustomItemsPanel}" />
```

But I came to know that this can be provided as

```
<.... ItemsPanel="Binding Source={StaticResource mycustomItemsPanel}}" />
```

What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing the binding will only be able on [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx), another would be that some objects behave differently when assigned as a `Binding.Source`, namely [`DataSourceProviders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.datasourceprovider.aspx).

> Common base class and contract for **DataSourceProvider** objects, which are factories that execute some queries to produce a single object or a list of objects that you can use as binding source objects.

The object provided by the `DataSourceProvider` then is used instead of the `DataSourceProvider` itself.

In this specific case there hence should be *no practical difference*.