# Binding ItemTemplate Property to Static Source

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to work out binding the `ItemTemplate` property of `ItemsControl` then i saw these two ways of binding that i am not getting how they differ ?

```
ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeDataTemplate}}"
```

and

```
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeDataTemplate}"
```

So what's the difference  between two ?

any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718684/what-is-the-difference-between-using-binding-with-staticresource-and-using-st

Comment: As per my knowledge http://prntscr.com/48625v... for Itemtemplate you need to use "{StaticResource SomeDataTemplate}"